# using a subquery to get results sql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a select statement that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_name 
FROM categories c JOIN products p 
  ON c.category_id = p.category_id 
ORDER BY category_name;
```

This returns:

```
+---------------+
| category_name |
+---------------+
| Basses        |
| Drums         |
| Guitars       |
+---------------+
```

I'm trying to get the same results using a subquery but I don't get the exact same thing. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_name FROM 
categories WHERE category_name IN(SELECT distinct 
category_name FROM products) ORDER BY category_name;
```

When I run this code I get:

```
+---------------+
| category_name |
+---------------+
| Basses        |
| Brass         |
| Drums         |
| Guitars       |
| Keyboards     |
+---------------+
```

What am I doing wrong that I'm not getting the same output?

Comment: One is comparing category names and the other category ids.  Different queries, so it is not surprising that they yield different results.  Why you would have the id and name in both tables is a different question altogether.

Comment: @GordonLinoff OK I see the mistake now. I changed category_name to category_id and got the correct result. Thank you for pointing that out, Gordon :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using a join if you would use a outer join this should work. 
Take a look at: [inner join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)